# Insert # in bibtex entry?

Tags: bibtex, symbols

How do i insert a # in a bibtex entry.. seem to be impossible it **does not recognize the `\#` or `#` as simple hashtag (#)..**

```
@ONLINE {DMA,
    title = "AR# 57550 - Example Designs - Designing with the AXI DMA core",
    month = "aug",
    year  = "2015",
    url   = "http://www.xilinx.com/support/answers/57550.html"
}
```

Comment: have you tried `\#`?

Comment: ` ` was missing..

Comment: Note that if the hash is followed by text, e.g., `#text`, it won't work.Use `\#{}text` to separate the hash from the text.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try to use `url` package and type

```
\url{\#}
```

Comment: This is using a sledgehammer. Just `\#` is sufficient.

Comment: @egreg It didn't worked for BibTeX neither for the Lamda nor for me

Comment: @OlegSoloviev From the comment http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/312226/insert-in-bibtex-entry#comment759691_312226 I think `\#` worked for lambda (beware that the system has its difficulties in displaying the backslash)

Comment: @samcarter that comment was about the first edits of the question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/312226/revisions

Comment: the MWE from egreg's answer works perfectly for me; I don't know why I haven't obtained the same result yesterday.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a minimal example:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@ONLINE {DMA,
    title = "AR\# 57550 - Example Designs - Designing with the AXI DMA core",
    month = aug,
    year  = "2015",
    url   = "http://www.xilinx.com/support/answers/57550.html"
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\begin{document}

\cite{DMA}

\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

As usual in examples, I use the `filecontents*` environment; `natbib` is just for convenience.

[image]